# Sylow Theorems Applications

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

I am working on the following question:

> Let $G$ a group of order $56$ and Q a normal Sylow 2-subgroup. If $P$ is a Sylow $7-$group prove that $G=P\times Q$ or $Q=C_2 \times C_2 \times C_2.$

I am almost done with the problem, I just need help in one detail.

That is the solution I have so far (following the hint the professor gave me): Let $P$ acting on $Q/\{1\}$ by conjugation. Then, by the Orbit-Stabilizer Theorem we have that $Stab(x)\leqslant P$ and $[P:Stab(x)]=|Orb(x)|$ for all $x \in Q/\{1\}$. Now since $|P|=7$ then $Stab(x)={1}$ or $P$ which means that $|Orb(x)|=1$ or $7$ and, because of this, the action is either trivial or transitive.

If the action is trivial then we have $\{x\}=Orb(x)=\{p\cdot x; p\in P\} = \{pxp^{-1},p\in P\}$ for all $x \in Q/\{1\}$. Then $x=pxp^{-1}$ for all $x \in Q/\{1\}$ and all $p\in P$ that is, $P$ is normal. Then $G=P\times Q.$

Now I know that $|Q|=8$, but how can I conclude that $Q=(C_2)^3$ from the fact that the action is transitive?

Any hint?

Answer (score 2):

You have to verify that $Q$ has no automorphisms of order $7$ unless $Q\simeq C_2^3$. Otherwise the semidirect product $Q\rtimes P$ is automatically a direct product.

If $\sigma:Q\to Q$ is an automorphism of order seven, and $x\in Q$ is such that $\sigma(x)\neq x$. Prove that in that case:

- All the elements $\sigma^j(x), j=0,1,2,\ldots,6$, are distinct and of the same order.
- Therefore those elements must all be the non-identity elements of $Q$. As they all have the same order, that order must be two (prove that!)
- Therefore $Q$ must be abelian, and isomorphic to $C_2^3$.
- The automorphisms of $C_2^3$ are the invertibles  $\Bbb{F}_2$-linear transformations from $\Bbb{F}_2^3$ to itself. Thus the group of automorphisms is $$Aut(Q)=GL_3(\Bbb{F}_2).$$ This group is known to have order $168$. Therefore it has an automorphism of order seven. In particular there exists a non-abelian semidirect product $(C_2^3)\rtimes C_7$.

Comment: Thank you @Jyrki Lahtonen. I just did not understand how automorphisms came to the game, can you explain?

Comment: Sorry about leaving that out @bttmbrcelo. My answer is sketchy in other ways as well. Editing it shortly. You were given that $Q$ is normal, so we always have $G=Q\rtimes P$, and the question is whether that is actually a direct product or not. It is direct if and only if the conjugation action of $P$ on $Q$ is trivial. For it to be non-trivial, conjugatiion by a generator of $P$ must be an automorphism of $Q$ of order seven. This forces $Q$ to be an elementary 2-abelian group.